# Find where line-segments can intersect with a box

Tags: geometry

I am trying to figure out where a bunch of line-segments clip into a window around them. I saw the [Liang–Barsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liang%E2%80%93Barsky_algorithm) algorithm, but that seems to assume the segments already intersect with the edges of the box, which these do not.

Say I have a box from `(0,0)` to `(26,16)`, and the following segments:

```
A: (7,6) - (16,3)
B: (10,6) - (19,6)
C: (13,10) - (21,3)
D: (16,12) - (19,14)
```

**Illustration:**

[image]

I imagine I need to extend the segments to a certain `X` or `Y` point, till they hit the edge of the window, but I don't know how.

How would I find the points where these segments, when extended, will intersect into the edge of the box? For instance, segment `B`, when extended, will intersect the box at `(0,6)` and `(26,6)`.

Comment: Liang-Barsky or some other clipping algorithm isn’t really appropriate here since you’re doing the *opposite* of clipping: instead of trimming a line segment you’re extending it. Also, there appears to be an unstated assumption that the sides of the clipping box are parallel to the coordinate axes.

Comment: @amd Correct, the sides of the box will always be parallel to the coordinate axes. I have sorted ot a solution already based on G Cab's answer, but will be trying out other answers to test processing efficiency.

Comment: The only way to really gain any efficiency would be to somehow determine which sides are going to be hit so that you don’t have to compute all four intersections, but doing that is likely to be at least as expensive as simply performing the small number of arithmetic operations needed to find an intersection.

Answer (score 2):

Parametrise the lines using $t$:
$$\begin{cases}
x(t) = x_0 + t ( x_1 - x_0 ) \\
y(t) = y_0 + t ( y_1 - y_0 ) \end{cases}$$
Note that for $t = 0$, $x(t) = x_0$ and $y(t) = y_0$, and for $t = 1$, $x(t) = x_1$ and $y(t) = y_1$.

To find where the line intersects with $x_C$, solve $x(t) = x_C$ for $t$:
$$t = \frac{x_C - x_0}{x_1 - x_0}$$
If $x_1 = x_0$, there is no solution, because the line is vertical, or degenerate (a point).

To find where the line intersects with $y_C$, solve $y(t) = y_C$ for $t$:
$$t = \frac{y_C - y_0}{y_1 - y_0}$$
Again, if $y_1 = y_0$, there is no solution, because the line is horizontal, or degenerate (a point).

If the line is not horizontal or vertical or degenerate, you get two solutions $t$ for the vertical edges, and two solutions for the horizontal edges. If the line segment is contained within the box, then two of the solutions are negative, and two positive. The correct intersections are then the larger of the negative $t$, and the smaller of the positive $t$.

To find the actual coordinates of the intersection point, use the formula for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, above.

Answer (score 0):

Given two points $A,B$, the line through them has equation $(y-y_A)/(y_B-y_A)=(x-x_A)/(x_B-x_A)$, which - to account for the due comment by *amd* - we shall better write as $ (y-y_A)(x_B-x_A)=(x-x_A)(y_B-y_A)$ so that vertical and horizontal lines are included.

Then

- put in it $x=0$  and determine if the resulting $y$ is comprised
  between $0$ and $16$: if yes keep the point $(0,y)$ as intersection, if not discard;
- same for $x=26$
- then introduce in the equation $y=0$ and check the resulting $0 \le x \le 26$, again keep/discard the point if yes/no
- same for $y=16$

You will definitely end with keeping exactly two points, apart from possible duplication when the intersection is exactly on a corner. In this case discard any duplicated point.

**example:**

1st segment : $(7,6),(16,3) \quad \to \quad x_A=7,\; x_B=16,\; y_A=6,\; y_B=3$

equation: $(y-6)9=(x-7)(-3)\; \to; 3y=25-x$

points:
$x=0, y=25/3\;$, YES
$x=26,y=-1/3\;$, NO
$x=25, y=0\;$, YES
$x=-23, y=16\;$, NO

Comment: It's been a long time since highschool algebra, when doing this I need to simplify the equation to put `y` or `x` on one side correct?

Comment: I tried solving for `y` or `x` a couple times for segment `A` and am getting incorrect answers, could you provide one example with that equation?

Comment: Your equation for the line excludes vertical lines.

Comment: @amd: right observation, thanks for signalling. For computational purposes the line equation can be rewritten as amended in my answer, or in case take due note for vertical lines.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: you have to solve an equation in two variables: given $x$ to find $y$ or v.v.. Normally you arrange the equation as to put all the "known" terms on RHS, and leave the variable to be determined on LHS with coefficient $1$.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: is it clear now? is it what you were looking for?